# 500 server error occurs while inserting bulk records in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml-parsing, bulkinsert

I got 500 server error while inserting the bulk records in mysql table.

The process flow was, i am feeding xml file which have 5000 more records with 6MB file using PHP script, to inserting in MySQL table. it loads the page and inserting all records to MySQL table. but the page shows "500 server error" after inserting 1,500 records in database, the inserting process is ongoing till all the records inserted. finally all records get inserted and page till showing 500 server error.

I have set the below config in php.ini file.

```
memory_limit = 2048M
max_input_time = 60000000
max_execution_time = 60000000
post_max_size = 300M
upload_max_filesize = 250M
```

Comment: 500 error means "Look harder for the real error" - not "guess what the solution might be"

Comment: Your web server's error log will just about always have more information when the server sends a 500.  That's where you start.  Make sure PHP error reporting is turned up `error_reporting = E_ALL`